# How to create an Android Live Wallpaper with Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to create an Android Live Wallpaper (LWP) using Delphi XE5 (with Android development add-on of course)?
It is fairly easy to develop a simple app for Android with Delphi XE5, but I could not find any info on how to make a LWP. Does anyone have any pointers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll find anything. Not yet a while, anyway.

Delphi's Android support is quite new and is targeted essentially at business apps.

Whilst it is feasible to do do other things, most of the interesting things involve a lot of cumbersome chicanery to, say, add a splash screen or launch other installed activities and get results.

I daresay similar amounts of effort could be put towards setting up a live wallpaper, but there is no info on how to do so with Delphi as yet.

Interestingly, it's the first time I've seen live wallpaper mentioned as a desired target for Delphi. Mostly it's services and broadcast receivers (which are also eminently feasible, but again markedly involved).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think Delphi (with Firemonkey) actually has a lot of potential for nice LWPs. If I succeed in making one, I'll update here.